# Installing EV multidomain ssl on SAS windows

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

I sold an EV multidomain SSL to an Org

The SAS hostname is a SAN of the ssl. The person who will install the SSL on SAS says he needs FQHN (FQDN?) that is CN not SAN of the SSL. Is this true?

Anyone has experience installing multidomain ssl on SAS? Helps please. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by SAS? I don't think you are referring to hard drives, but that is the tag that you used.

Comment: sas.com , it's for a SAS web app

Comment: OK, so it's a service provider. Well then. Use of the CN was deprecated years ago - in 2000! AFAIK it is no longer actually used by any user agents, and no software should ever require it.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with SAS but he was already given the 3 files he needed in pem format - crt, ca bundle and the pkey.

Comment: Those would be the correct files. At this point you probably need to be yelling at SAS, or "the person who will install the SSL on SAS" for their apparent incompetence.

Comment: Yes but he is concerned about the host name for the SAS in the ssl. Since he only had experience installing individual or wild card ssl with the host name as the CN. In this case the host name is the SAN of the ssl. So he wants the ssl reissued and the host name made as the CN or a buy an individual ssl for the SAS host name

Comment: So he doesn't understand that the CN does not need to be present at all? It sounds like he needs some education. I'm not sure how we can help with that, though.